# Batch Insertion gives NullReferenceException when UpdateBatchSize is greater than 1

Tags: c#, mysql, nullreferenceexception, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert 10,000 rows (or more) using the `dataAdapter.Update()` function. But whenever I change my DataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize to some value other than 1, it throws `NullReferenceException` (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

My current implementation is on C# with MySQL. And my data table has around 50 columns.

StackTrace is as following

> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.GetCommandTextForBatching()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter.AddToBatch(IDbCommand
>   command)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[]
>   dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable
>   dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable)    at DTAR.DataAccessLib.DataX.BulkInsert(DataTable dTable,
>   String tableName, String& message) in "project"\DataX.cs:line 991

my function for is as following

```
    public int BulkInsert(DataTable dTable, string tableName, out string message)
    {
        try
        {
            message = string.Empty;
            m_DBType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBMS"].ToLower();
            int batchSize = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateBatchSize"].ToString());
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdaptor = GetDataAdaptor("select * from " + tableName + " limit 1", CommandType.Text) as MySqlDataAdapter;
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(tableName);
            dataAdaptor.Fill(dataSet, tableName);
            MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder((MySqlDataAdapter)dataAdaptor);
            MySqlCommand command = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
            foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Unchanged)
                    row.SetAdded();

                dataSet.Tables[0].ImportRow(row);
            }
            commandBuilder.Dispose();
            dataAdaptor.InsertCommand = command;
            dataAdaptor.UpdateBatchSize = batchSize;
            dataAdaptor.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
            int result = dataAdaptor.Update(dataSet, tableName);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.m_DBConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need at least the stacktrace of the exception. More details please.

Comment: @adricadar I don't think this is simple NullReferenceException case. As I've already told that my code works when I use UpdateBatchSize = 1. But it wont work once I change it to any value other than 1

Comment: @adricadar as you can see, error is occurring at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.GetCommandTextForBatching(). which is MySqlClient for .net. Its outside scope of my code. Although after a long debugging, I could only find that changing UpdateBatchSize to 1 (which in turns, goes query by query instead of batch querying) error vanishes. Which isn't exactly my requirement